# CI/CD gitlab-runner accessing another user directory and files

Tags: git, raspberry-pi, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have been experimenting with Gitlab CI/CD and I have an idea on how to optimize our current workflow. In order to achieve this, I need to be able to access and automatically execute scripts via CI/CD pipeline.

For the experiment, I have a Raspberry PI with a main user `lukas`. On the same machine (Raspberry PI), I have configured gitlab-runner and assigned it to my repository to execute pipelines.

See the screenshot below to see 2 users in my Raspberry PI home directory:

```
lukas@raspberrypi:/ $ ls
bin   dev  home        initrd.img.old  lost+found  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var      vmlinuz.old
boot  etc  initrd.img  lib             media       opt  root  sbin  sys  usr  vmlinuz
lukas@raspberrypi:/ $ cd home
lukas@raspberrypi:/home $ ls
gitlab-runner  lukas
```

The pipeline that I am trying to run:

```
# List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
stages:
  - test


test-job1:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - raspberrypi
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"

    - cd /home/lukas/Scripts
    - ls -l
```

The error I am getting:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.7.0 (102c81ba)
  on Raspberry PI TestTool runner htiDWYJ2, system ID: s_0ae6b2582ae5
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (bash) executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on raspberrypi...
Getting source from Git repository
00:05
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/htiDWYJ2/0/embeded-programmers/gitchangelog-test/.git/
Checking out 0f2827a6 as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ echo "This job tests something"
This job tests something
$ cd /home/lukas/Scripts
bash: line 149: cd: /home/lukas/Scripts: Permission denied
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

The error above is expected since the gitlab-runner starts on a seperate `gitlab-runner` user and it does not have any access to my main user `lukas`.

**What I have tried so far:**

**Method 1**

I can place my Scripts in /tmp folder - this way `gitlab-runner` is going to have access to those files but I prefer to not use this method.

**Method 2**

I have tried to grant sudo permissions to the `gitlab-runner` by using command:

`sudo usermod -a -G sudo gitlab-runner`

and in the sudo editor:

`sudo visudo`

I have added the following to the bottom:

`gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

But when trying to rerun the job, I am still not able to enter the directory due to permission issue.

**Method 3**

Use `sudo cp` command to copy the required files/scripts to the `gitlab-user` for example:

`sudo cp -r home/lukas/Scripts home/gitlab-user`

This way, gitlab user can access those Scripts.

I want to know if Method 3 is safe and should be used for production?

**Method 4**

Change the Scripts directory ownership:
 `sudo chown gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner Scripts`. The results:

```
lukas@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas lukas 4096 Dec  5 04:47 Bookshelf
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas lukas 4096 Jan  9 09:26 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas lukas 4096 Jan  2 07:30 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas lukas 4096 Jan  3 05:45 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas lukas 4096 Jan  2 07:30 Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas lukas 4096 Jan  2 07:30 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas lukas 4096 Jan  2 07:30 Public
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas lukas 4096 Jan  9 09:36 Scripts
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas lukas 4096 Jan  2 07:30 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 9 lukas lukas 4096 Jan  9 09:11 test-tool-binaries
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas lukas 4096 Jan  2 07:30 Videos
lukas@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo chown gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner Scripts
lukas@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas         lukas         4096 Dec  5 04:47 Bookshelf
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas         lukas         4096 Jan  9 09:26 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas         lukas         4096 Jan  2 07:30 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas         lukas         4096 Jan  3 05:45 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas         lukas         4096 Jan  2 07:30 Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas         lukas         4096 Jan  2 07:30 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas         lukas         4096 Jan  2 07:30 Public
drwxr-xr-x 2 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner 4096 Jan  9 09:36 Scripts
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas         lukas         4096 Jan  2 07:30 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 9 lukas         lukas         4096 Jan  9 09:11 test-tool-binaries
drwxr-xr-x 2 lukas         lukas         4096 Jan  2 07:30 Videos
```

Trying to rerun the JOB still fails due to permission issue (same as Method 2).

I want to know which method is the most appropriate.

Comment: You should change permissions on `/home/lukas/Scripts` so `gitlab-runner` user will have access to it. Or just transfer ownership of these scripts to `gitlab-runner` user.

Comment: I am complete noob when it comes to file permissions. I have tried to change the ownerhip of ```/home/lukas/Scripts``` by executing the following command:```sudo chown gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner Scripts```. After that, I have confirmed that the ownership has changed by listing the files using ```ls -l```. I can see that the Scripts directory is now owned by gitlab-runner. However, I still cannot do ```cd /home/lukas/Scripts``` via CI/CD pipeline due to permission issue. I have also posted more details regarding this  in my initial post above (Method 4)

Comment: ¿What about `/home/lukas` permissions?

Comment: ```/home/lukas``` belongs to user ```lukas``` because that is his user directory. I dont think changing main users directory ownership is a good idea but that explains why I could not access the ```Scripts``` directory even though I have changed the ownership. So are you suggesting to change the ```/home/lukas``` ownership to ```gitlab-user``` ?

Comment: I'm suggesting to change permissions (`chmod`) so gitlab-runner user will have access to it.

Comment: That makes sense! Since ```gitlab-user``` belongs to ```lukas``` group, I have did the following: ```chmod g+rwx lukas``` (I gave the Group permission to read write execute) for ```/home/lukas``` directory. Now my pipeline can run without any issues since ```gitlab-runner``` can access ```lukas``` directory